# Weird Stack Exchange logo on 404 pages on high-resolution screens

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, 404-not-found, retina

https://test.stackexchange.com

A picture with freehand circle says more than 6-8 hundred words:

[image]

This happens for me on Safari, Firefox and Chrome on macOS 10.13.1 (latest browser versions, caches have been cleaned) but not on Chrome 62 on Windows 10:

[image]

---

Other users (see comments) report mixed results on similar browsers, and it looks like only devices with a high pixel density (e.g. Mac Retina screens) are affected, because the CSS rule below is applied only for devices with `min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5`:

```
header h1 {
    background: transparent url('img/se-logo@2x.png?v=5663d7dbb7ab') no-repeat left top;
    background-size: 223px 52px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I can repro this on Windows with FF and Chrome.

Comment: no repro in firefox (developer edition) or chrome on Mac

Comment: https://imgur.com/opiSSk6 this is from chrome Android.. maybe more to do with screen size

Comment: @Suraj Rao Same with me in Chrome 62 on Android. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiHR9.jpg

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 62 on Android, Samsung Galaxy Tab S2.

Comment: Still present with Chrome 67 and Safari 12 on macOS 10.14.

Comment: Is this still present? It seems that nowadays, similar links redirect to https://stackexchange.com/site-not-found and the logo (at least for me, on Chrome/Windows) looks fine.

Comment: @41686d6564 no. It looks like they've added a `text-indent: -999em;` to make sure it's never displayed. No idea when that happened ...

Comment: @Glorfindel Should this be retagged [status-completed] in that case?

Comment: @41686d6564 I can ping a staff member when I'm back from holiday, perhaps they can shed some light on the fix.

Comment: @Glorfindel Sorry for bugging you. Enjoy your holiday :)